# Python Paho/MQTT : Detecting Connect error

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

In short, I have a Paho/MQTT sample set that works fine, but I'm having trouble detecting errors.  Specifically, I'm not getting an on_connect callback and when an invalid UserID/Pswd combination is given, it fails silently.
In fact, by every indication, it all worked fine!

What am I doing wrong?

```
(snip)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with flags [%s] rtn code [%d]"% (flags, rc) )

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("disconnected with rtn code [%d]"% (rc) )

def on_publish(client, userdata, msgID):
    print("Published with MsgID [%d]"% (msgID) )


mqttc = mqtt.Client()
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
mqttc.on_publish = on_publish

mqttc.username_pw_set(Q_USER, Q_PSWD)

rc=mqttc.connect(Q_BROKER, Q_PORT)
print "Return="+str(rc)

mqttc.loop_start()
rc=mqttc.publish(Q_TOPIC, "Hello, World!")
print "Return="+str(rc)

mqttc.disconnect()
mqttc.loop_stop()
```

Output when UserID or Pswd is deliberately wrong:

```
Return=0
Published with MsgID [1]
Return=(0, 1)
disconnected with rtn code [0]
```

Comment: To add to the confusion...  If I move the loop_start() BEFORE the connect() call, the message doesn't post properly.  Still no error indications

Comment: Which broker are you using and how have you configured the authentication? e.g. if mosquitto is `allow_anonymous` true?

Comment: Note that a loop_start() before the connect() call is known to produce undefined results.

Comment: Is there a way to find out if the connection to a MQTT broker succeeded apart from the on_conenct callback rc parameter  when using paho-mqtt in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that it was a few different issues.

- First, Connect returns without truly being connected. Adding a wait loop with a Sleep until the Connect callback is received is crucial.  Only the callback tells you the Connect succeeded or failed.
- Second, once I saw the return code, I saw mine was failing on Protocol Version Mismatch.  The Mosquitto version my Pi was pulling down was REALLY old. Found a post that pointed my system to a newer version. Solved the version mismatch problem.
- Third, adding the "loop_start()" before Connect does not work. The intuitive place is not the right place.
- Fourth, one needs to add Sleep() calls before Disconnect, or you will not see all the Callbacks.

Bottom line, while the docs show how to use the APIs, they don't show you how to write a robust program for production use.

I'm still still looking for ways to know when all in-flight publish calls have cleared, rather than using a blind Sleep call, but my original issue is resolved.

Comment: Had you able to producer a working code to get the status code?

Answer (score 0):

When you send mqtt CONNECT packet, you should receive CONNACK response. This response contains the following codes 
0 - success, connection accepted 
1 - connection refused, bad protocol 
2 - refused, client-id error 
3 - refused, service unavailable
4 - refused, bad username or password 
5 - refused, not authorized
As you can see, your response should be **4**. But it is **zero**. It might be that you broker doesn't check credentials so your **connect** message is accepted. Client looks fine.

Comment: Notice 1) I wasn't seeing a connect response at all and 2) I was using QOS of '0'
So the connect had never succeeded, and since I sent as fire-and-forget, the RC will always be '0'.  Once I upped the QOS level, I got message send error.  Also, once I processed the Callbacks successfully, I saw I was getting a Connect error of '1' (old Mosquitto version didn't support 3.11 client protocol version)

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the `publish` into a `while` loop like this

```
while True:
    mqttc.loop()
    rc=mqttc.publish(Q_TOPIC, "Hello, World!")
    print("Return=" + str(rc))
    if sth:
        break
mqttc.disconnect()
```

In this way, the callback function may be executed before the program ends.

Comment: I'm new to MQTT, but to me, this will repeatedly publish the same message.  And what is "sth"?
The answer seems to be looking for the on_publish to make it through.

Comment: Here I mean if you don't put the `publish` into a `while` loop, the program will terminate before the callback function is triggerred. `sth` here means any condition that can help to control the loop.   Actually I remembered that I had encountered the same situation but can't clearly think of the solution.   I suggest you have a try.

Comment: Agreed. See the fourth point in my answer. Currently I use a Sleep, but would love a more robust and accurate way to know when all Published messages have been addressed.